# Does Tryptic Soy Agar (TSA) contain L-cysteine? (Question about Legionella)

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology

I ask because *Legionella* sp. requires the presence of cysteine. If TSA does contain L-cysteine, is it sufficient to grow *Legionella*?

Comment: Legionella also requires other nutrients. Our general recipe includes ACES, Bacto Agar, Charcoal, Yeast extract, L-cysteine, ferric pyrophosphate, potassium hydroxide to make BCYE agar which is used to grow legionella.